# WATCH / UNWATCH Redis key outside a transaction

Tags: caching, redis, race-condition

I'm relatively new to Redis and trying to understand how I can use WATCH / UNWATCH to address a concurrency / race condition issue.

All of the documentation I've read describes WATCH in the context of a transaction, but can I WATCH and UNWATCH a key if no transaction occurs?

Here is the scenario:

- I need to modify an object in cache but due to TTL I cannot guarantee that object exists
- I don't want to fetch the object, check it exists, and then call WATCH, because it is possible for TTL to expire between fetching and WATCHing.
- Solution is to WATCH the key, fetch the object, check it exists, and UNWATCH the key if the object doesn't exist

Is this workflow possible, and is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you don't use transaction, `WATCH` is useless. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @for_stack the intention is to prevent a race condition where two calls try to add an object for the same key. If caller A 1) checks for a key's existence, 2) finds it empty, and then 3) sets the object, it's possible that caller B already set the object between 2) and 3)

Comment: You can use `SET` with `NX` option, i.e. Only set the key if it does not already exist.Only set the key if it does not already exist.